# Dynamic method generation in scala macros

Tags: scala, macros

I want to know if the solution to the following problem is possible via scala macros.

I have following class and method.

```
    class Main{
      def test(s: String) : String = {
       1.initialize some variables.
       2.do some operations.
       3.as a result some values of variables are changed.
       4.do further operations.
       5. return some string
      }

      test("some string")
    }
```

I want to

- access the variables on line 3 (this is decided dynamically)
- end test method after taking snapshot of all variables. So lines 4 and 5 are eliminated from test method.
- create new method (say test2)
- initialize the snapshotted variables in test2 method
- compute the remaining part of test method, via test2 with snapshotted variables.

You can think of as, dividing the method test into two separate methods, with taking snapshot of variables where the division is made.

Example input code :

```
 foo(){
    int i = 0;
    for (int k = 0; k < 100; k++){
        i=i+k;
    }

    for (int k = 0; k < 20; k++){
       i=i*k;
    }
 }

main() {
 foo();
}

Output code:

    foo1(){
     int i = 0;
     for (int k = 0; k < 100; k++){
        i=i+k;
     }
    }
    foo2(Any[] vars){
     initialize variables with 'vars' needed for the code below
     for (int k = 0; k < 20; k++){
       i=i*k;
     }
    }
    main() {
     Any[]vars =  foo1();
     foo2(vars);
    }
```

Comment: I'm glad I read this, I did not know about macros :p

Comment: For dinamically do you intend at runtime? If yes the answer is not unless it's the access method itself that is dynamic (i.e. with reflection). Macros are compile time only

Comment: I mean compile time. What I meant by dynamic is this: while anaylising the code inside method test, I can generate dynamic number of additional  methods. In example it was 1, which is test2. However, depending on the code inside method test, I can divide it to 3,4 or n number of additional methods.

Comment: Could you give a concrete example of the code that you write and the code that you'd like to get after macro expansion?

Comment: @EugeneBurmako Sorry for late response. I edited the question accordingly.